# Using odd index to return odd numbers JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to solve a problem on a testing website and I'm getting confused on trying to find the odd numbers from a passed in array at odd index.

Code I have so far;

```
    function codeNation(arr) {
    let newArr = [];
    arr.forEach(function(value) {
      if (value % 2 !== 0) {
        newArr.push(value);
      }
    });
    return newArr;
  }
  
  console.log(codeNation([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]));
```

In the above example I want it to return [3, 7, 11] but I can't figure out how. Can you please fix my code and explain to me the best way of getting an odd number at an odd index from a passed in array to the function? The order of the numbers has to be retained.

Comment: In such case, always go back to `for` and try to implement it. This works for me. `const newArr = []; for (let i =1; i<arr.length; i+=2 ) { arr[i] %2 !== 0 && (newArr.push(arr[i]))}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- So what you are doing wrong here is that you are not checking the index. that's why you are not getting desired output.
- To solve your problem what I did is that I used Array's `filter` method and then first check if the index is odd or not, if it's odd then I am checking whether the value is odd or not is its odd then we return the value.

  ```js
  function codeNation(arr) {
    const result = arr.filter((value, i) => {
      if (i % 2 != 0) {
        if (value % 2 != 0) {
          return value;
        }
      }
    })
    return result;
  }

  console.log(codeNation([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]));
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I understand what to use now.

Answer (score 0):

Уou need to use an `index` to determine if it is odd or not.
But you can also reduce the amount of code and increase readability if use `.filter`

```js
const isOdd = (num) => Boolean(num % 2);
const odds = (arr) => arr.filter((value, index) => isOdd(value) && isOdd(index));

console.log(odds([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**we can make this way too**

filter will give itself true values only we no need to check values if or else

```js
const oddIndexValues =(ar)=>{
const getValues = ar.filter((e, i)=> i%2 && e%2)
return getValues
}
console.log(oddIndexValues([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]))
```